# Conda packages leaked into my old venv, also I cannot deactivate it

Tags: python, pycharm, conda, python-venv

I installed Conda on Windows, played with it a bit and returned to my old project. Generally, his venv works as usual, except of at least two things:

1. The installed package list `pip freeze -l` is littered with global packages (specifically non-conda ones, somehow)
2. I cannot deactivate it with any command be it `deactivate`, `source deactivate` or `conda deactivate`, on first two I receive `DeprecationWarning: 'deactivate' is deprecated. Use 'conda deactivate'`, on the last nothing happens, `(venv)` identifier just stays put.

What's strange, when I create a new venv in test folder, the issue just isn't there at all. Obviously, Conda messed up my old venv... somehow. It may possibly be connected to me re-creating this venv using PyCharm (that was after the Conda installation), though in the project settings I clearly set the interpreter to be the vanilla non-Conda one (version 3.9.0). Would be grateful for suggestions.